# Список контактов с аватарками в ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода аватарок контактов в ListView.

Пробовал разными методами - сувать напрямую bitmap или URI в ImageView, а так-же uvinersal image loader.

Имеется метод вывода аватарки контакта:

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id, Context context) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    Log.i("log_tag", "URI = " + uri);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input == null) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.standart_contact);
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

В адаптере, в методе getView, пробовал варинты:

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(ContactPhotoHelper.loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver(), p.id, getApplicationContext()));
```

---

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, p.id);
holder.image.setImageURI(uri);
```

---

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, p.id);
imageLoader.displayImage(uri.toString(), holder.image, options);
```

В первых двух случаях ужасные задержки открытия окна, и толку никакого. Первый вариант втыкает везде "заглушки", второй не выводит ничего.

image loader в своих логах каждому элементу пишет, что файл отсутсвует, хотя у меня есть контакты с аватарками. Соответственно всем он втыкает "заглушку".

E/ImageLoader(19559): File does not exist; URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/714

Подскажите, как грамотно вывести эти аватарки?

---

Полный листинг адаптера после внесения изменений:

```
class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView telephone;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userContacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userContacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final Contact p = getContact(position);

        listener = new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                . . .
        };

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
            holder.telephone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tel_tv);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_icon);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (view != convertView) {
            view.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        }

        holder.name.setText(p.name);
        holder.telephone.setText(p.tel);

        final Uri uri = getPhotoUri(p.id);

        Log.i("getView", p.id + " " + p.name + " " + p.tel + " URI = " + uri);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri != null?
                    uri.toString(): null, holder.image, options);

        return view;
    }

    Contact getContact(int position) {
        return ((Contact) getItem(position));
      }

    public Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) {
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Решил проблему следующим образом:
Включил в класс Contact численную переменную для хранения Contact.PHOTO_ID. Порывшись на StackOverFlow нашел рабочий метод, который по PHOTO_ID выдает битмап. Прикрутил AsyncTask, все работает.

Только вот остался баг с повторением картинок. Судя по логам, никто туда эту картинку не вставляет, она почему-то появляется сама. 
Кроме того, при пролистывании списка, после загрузки аватарки на контакте (где она есть), метод getView() аж 4 раза заново перебирает элементы списка, которые видны на самой верхней позиции списка. Это видно из логов. Не пойму в чем косяк

Answer (score 2):

```
final Uri uri = getPhotoUri(Long.parseLong(viewHolder.id));

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri != null?
                    uri.toString(): null, viewHolder.picture, options);

----------------------------

public static Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) {
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }
```

Comment: Теперь ImageLoader обращается по пути  content://com.android.contacts/contacts/284/photo, и так-же там ничего не находит, выдает java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: а ты уверен что аватарка на контакте есть? на каком апи проверяешь?

Comment: Уверен. Стандартный список контактов отображает.
Проверяю на 16 API. Samsung Galaxy SII 4.1.2 официальная прошивка.

Comment: попробуй проверить на эмуляторе

Comment: В общем, вылезла одна аватарка, и то не на том контакте, где должна быть.

ID'шники по логам правильные.

Сейчас убрал из параметров ImageLoader все "заглушки" и получился интересный результат:
При первой прокрутке списка, аватарок ни у кого нет - просто пустые ImageView. Когда я долистал до той единственной аватарки, то при пролистывании в любую сторону, как только эта аватарка исчезает за экраном, то у первого появившегося контакта будет эта-же аватарка. Так-же будет и с этой аватаркой. Если много раз пролистать список туда-сюда, то постепенно заполняется весь список этой аватаркой.

Comment: покажи свой list adapter

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

UPD: Сдается мне, что иконки имеют свои ID, которые не совпадают с ID контакта. У меня так получилось, что ID одной из иконок случайно совпало с одним из контактов.

Comment: ну даже если бы просто совпало - она не должна прыгать

Comment: Вообще рекомендуется использовать не id контакта, а lookup key контакта. Id контакта иногда может меняться, а lookup key никогда.